# how to simplify this complex query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

This is an extract of one of my php functions. I'm struggling to get this optimized as is super slow, as I need to load all interview records, and then check if the current user is either assigned as `user_id` on the interview record, or if the `user->id` is in the interviews `shared_user_ids` which is json

```php
$interviews___ = interviews::whereIn('archived', [0, false, null])->sortBy('created_at')->reverse();
        $interviews__ = [];
        foreach($interviews___ as $in){
            $sameUser = $in->user_id == $user->id; // this line to...
            $ids_ = json_decode($in->shared_user_ids, true);
            $ids = [];
            foreach($ids_ as $id){
                $ids[] = (int)($id);
            }
            $containsUser = in_array($user->id, $ids);  // ...to this line
            if($sameUser || $containsUser){
                $interviews__[] = [
                    "id"=>$in->id,
                    "title"=>$in->title,
                    "created" => $in->created_at,                
                    "open_rate" => $in->getOpenRates(),
                    'total_leads' => $in->getLeads(),
                    'newOpensCounter' => $in->getNewOpens(),
                    'openDiff' => $in->getOpenDiff(),
                    'interview_count' => $in->getInterviewCount(),
                    'sent_count' => $in->getCount(),
                    'sent_count_marketing' => $in->getCountMarketing(),
                    'sent_count_vlog' => $in->sent_count_vlog,
                    'openedInterview' => $in->openedInterview ?? 0,
                    'openedBespoke' => $in->openedBespoke ?? 0,
                    'openedMarketing' => $in->openedMarketing ?? 0,
                    'openedVlog' => $in->openedVlog ?? 0,
                    'archived' => $in->archived
                ];
            }
        }
```

I'm also using PostgreSQL

## Edit - expected result

somehow create a sql query which does the user id checks for the user_id and the shared_user_id

then return only those which match the requirements

1. `archived` has a value of `(0, false, null)`  <- required
2. `user_id`  matches `user->id` [optional]
3. `user->id` in `shared_user_ids`  [optional]

Comment: Which part of your code is _complex_ and takes too long?

Comment: @Justinas i dont want to load all the records and then do the user id check, is there perhaps a pure sql way to get the results? i'm not that good at sql, but i believe this is possible

Comment: Why don't you have where/orWhere clause in the builder?

Comment: @AngelDeykov I'm new to laravel, so I dont know all these magic methods yet

Comment: Just as an FYI with Laravel, you can use the 'deleted_at' columns instead of using your own archived column. The ORM will automatically ignore archived records.https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to query the columns in the interview query itself. You can read more about querying JSON columns [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses).

You should also change the `sortBy` to `orderBy` since `sortBy` can only be used on collections.

```
$interviews___ = interviews::whereIn('archived', [0, false, null])
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->whereJsonContains('shared_user_ids', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('user_id', $user->id);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks, but I get an error of `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortBy()`

Comment: You need to use `orderBy` instead of `sortBy` on ORM/Query Builder. Updated my answer.

Comment: `$interviews___` is returning an empty array

Comment: If you replace `get()` with `toSql()` and perform a `dd()` on the `$interviews___` var you should get the raw SQL, if you can send me that and your table schema I'll have a look at it.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i  discussed this issue with my boss, and we have modified our system design, to avoid this issue completely

Comment: Not a problem! 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246459/discussion-between-thursday-dan-and-dean-van-greunen).

Comment: could we chat? a

Comment: could you check the chat please